# JavaScript built in methods how to skip the first iteration?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Can this be done without mutating the array?

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
arr.shift()  // works but mutates the array

arr.forEach(function(value) {
  console.log(value)
});

2
3
4
5
```

Comment: `[1,1,1].map((e,i) => i ? e*2 : e); // [1,2,2]`

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You could use [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) for a copy without the first element.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

arr.slice(1).forEach(function(value) {
    console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: Nice this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 14):

Use `index` in the `forEach`:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

arr.forEach(function(value, index) {
  if ( index != 0 ) {console.log(value) }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Though `array.slice(1).forEach(...)` is elegant, it does create a new array. You can avoid doing this by checking whether the second property passed to `forEach` (the array index) is `0`, or "falsy." If your passed function happens to only execute a single expression, you can shorten the statement:

`if (i) expression()` to `i && expression()`

...which makes this method surprisingly terse.

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

array.forEach(function (value, i) {
  if (i) console.log(value)
})

array.forEach(function (value, i) {
  i && console.log(value)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

arr.forEach(function(value, index) {
  return index == 0 ? true : console.log(value), true;
});
```

Comment: [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) does not care about return values.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr.forEach(function(value, index) {
    if(index !== 0) {
        console.log(value);
    }
});
```

this little if statement just fires if the value is not equal to the first array item

Comment: How about this array `[99,1,2,3,99,5,6]`?

Comment: @georg, good point i'll make an edit. Thanks